# reading excel file -> getting checkbox value

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

So i think ive tried everything now. Im trying to get the values from radiobuttons and checkboxes from an excel sheet. My first approach was to use the Excel Data Reader: http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/. The cells with checkboxes render empty.

Same thing if i use OLEDB;

```
string filename = @"C:\\" + "uploads\\SmartAuditSheet.xls";
        string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                                      "Data Source=" + filename + ";" +
                                      "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]",    connectionString);

        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "BookInfo");
        DataTable dataTable = myDataSet.Tables["BookInfo"];

        gv.DataSource = myDataSet;
        gv.DataBind();
```

Help please.

Comment: Will you have Excel installed on the machine? If so, have you tried [MS Office Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel(v=office.11).aspx)?

Comment: I have it, but i guess it wont work when i host the site on some webserver.

Comment: What types of controls are you using on the sheet?

Comment: @TimWilliams Checkboxes and radiobuttons

Comment: What type as in Forms controls or Activex ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using some 3rd-party library for that - there are several out there (free and commercial) that do NOT require Excel being installed:

- [OpenXML 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124) (free library from MS) can be used to read/modify the content of an .xlsx so you can do with it what you want
- [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) (free library) works with XLSX
- some (commercial) 3rd-party libraries come with grid controls allowing you to do much more with excel files (most can do not only XLSX but XLS too) in your application (be it Winforms/WPF/ASP.NET...) like [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/), [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx), [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try something like the following.

```
 OLEObject ole = (OLEObject)excelWorksheet.OLEObjects("Checkbox1");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool state = Convert.ToBoolean(ws.OLEObjects("Checkbox1").Object.value());
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the object values  using OpenXML. Below Code shows how to get checkbox object values using  OpenXML.

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
public static bool GetCheckBoxValue( String filePath )
{
    bool isChecked = false;
    using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, false))                   
    {
        WorkbookPart wbPart = document.WorkbookPart;
        // Sheet object to retrieve a reference to the first worksheet.
        Sheet theSheet = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == "Sheet1").FirstOrDefault();
        var control = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Control>().FirstOrDefault();
        var controlProperies = (ControlPropertiesPart)wsPart.GetPartById(control.Id);
        isChecked = controlProperies.FormControlProperties.Checked == "Checked";
    }
    return isChecked ;
}
```